# insert text at nth offset from start in command line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I've a file in which I get offset from starting position where I need to insert some text. For e.g. if the file looks like below

```
Hello World
How are you doing today?
I'm good. Thanks for asking.
```

I may get input like 3, 10, 25 offset from start where I've to `insert` text.

Is there a command-line way to do it? I have tried using `sed` but, it works line by line and does not honor offset from start. This is what I wrote for sed

```
sed 's/./&\
 inserted text\
   /25' in.txt > out.txt
```

What above does is - for every line, at 25th character, it inserts `inserted text` - but, I want it to be done at 25th offset from starting position of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by using a control character `RS` in `awk`. This makes whole file a single record for awk:

```
awk -v RS='\07' -v p=25 -v t='inserted text' '{
      print substr($0, 1, p) t substr($0, p+1)}' ORS= file

Hello World
How are you dinserted textoing today?
I'm good. Thanks for asking.
```

Comment: Can we write it back in the file, instead of printing?

Comment: Yes definitely `awk -v RS='\07' -v p=25 -v t='inserted text' '{print substr($0, 1, p) t substr($0, p+1)}' ORS= file > _file.tmp && mv _file.tmp file` or use `awk -i inplace -v RS='\07' -v p=25 -v t='inserted text' '{print substr($0, 1, p) t substr($0, p+1)}' ORS= file` (if using gnu awk)

Comment: How do I ensure if I am using gnu awk (I'm sorry, if this is too naive question)

Comment: Run `awk --version`

Comment: I get `awk version 20070501`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. One final question - I want my text in new line (if there are multiple line text, it should start from new line and end at new line) is that possible.

Comment: Just make `\n` part of replacement text as `awk -v RS='\07' -v p=25 -v t='\ninserted text\n' '{print substr($0, 1, p) t substr($0, p+1)}' ORS= file`

Comment: One more question, the in-place file replacement does not work well when original file is in different directory than _file.tmp. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use: `awk -v RS='\07' -v p=25 -v t='\ninserted text\n' '{print substr($0, 1, p) t substr($0, p+1)}' ORS= /some/dir/file > _file.tmp && mv _file.tmp /some/dir/file`

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241419/ors-command-to-modify-file-in-place?noredirect=1#comment69682432_41241419 - I have explained it better. I'm using same strategy.